# Word embeddings with documents and users

Tags: machine-learning

I understand how one can generate a latent vector space from a collection of words or documents, using something like Glove, word2vec, doc2vec, etc. I don't understand how this representation can be turned into features for something generating these documents at a "higher level", like a user or a product.

Here's a concrete example: I have users on a website who are generating reviews, which are written in English. Suppose I want to make a binary classification of users on whether or not they will stop using the site in the next month. How do I go from a word embedding, or a list of document embeddings for each user, into features for the user?

I believe this third level comes up a lot in practice. For example,

- users ->  multiple reviews -> words. Task: predict if a user will want to buy product X.
- items -> multiple reviews -> words. Task: group items into sales categories.
- artists -> multiple songs -> audio (audio embedded into a space). Task: group artists into genres.

I feel as though this is a common use case but I lack the vocabulary to search for it effectively. Apologies if this is a repeat question.

EDITED: I edited the question for clarify of the problem formulation.

Comment: Depends on the learning task.  What patterns do you expect to exist in the reviews that would help predict whether the user stops visiting the site?  I would have guessed that other factors, like frequency of reviews and frequency at which they visit the site, might be more predictive than the content of the reviews -- but I'm sure you know better than I.  If the contents of the review are useful, do you think only the last review will be useful, or all of them, and what kinds of patterns do you think will exist in the reviews?

Comment: In some contexts you might be able to use a LSTM on each review to classify each review in some particular way (e.g., sentiment analysis), then use techniques from time series analysis to deal with the sequence of reviews.  But this might be task/domain-specific.